# How to send the authentication token with the header in Ionic 4?

Tags: node.js, angular, ionic-framework, jwt, authorization

Without using HttpInterceptor, I would like to send a header which contains the authorization token to my backend. Here is my attempt to do so through a `Headers` object:

```
   import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions } from "@angular/http";
    getPoints() {
        var headers = new Headers();
        headers.append("Authorization", "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("token"));
        headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
        return this.http.get(environment.apiUrl + "/user/getCurrentPoints", {
          headers
        });
      }
```

In the backend I am using this middleware function to verify the token:

```
  var isAuthenticated = function(req, res, next) {
  var token = req.headers["Authorization"];
  console.log("mytoken is " + token);
  if (!token) {
    return res.status(401).json({
      error: null,
      msg: "You have to login first before you can access your lists.",
      data: null
    });
  }
  jwt.verify(token, req.app.get("secret"), function(err, decodedToken) {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(401).json({
        error: err,
        msg: "Login timed out, please login again.",
        data: null
      });
    }
    req.decodedToken = decodedToken;
    next();
  });
```

};

Here is the end point in my backend:

```
router.get(
  "/user/getCurrentPoints",
   isAuthenticated,
   userCtrl.getCurrentPoints
 );
```

The problem is I am always getting 401 error: `You have to login first before you can access your lists.` Also, I get that my token is undefined, in the backend. Am I sending the token incorrectly to the backend?

Comment: what's the output of `console.log("mytoken is " + token);`? Also, when you read the Authoization header lik ethis, you'll also read the word Bearer, so you have to remove that from the result.

Comment: @jps The output in the console is undefined.

Comment: @jps I also removed the Bearer from the header, and I am still getting the same error

Answer (score 1):

Try Below code

```
const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem("token")
    })
  };
this.httpClientObj.get(environment.apiUrl + "/user/getCurrentPoints", httpOptions);
```

Comment: I think the quotation marks are not closed correctly

Comment: Do I have to remove Bearer though, as my backend does not split the header, or is it done automatically?

Comment: No you have to Bearer in Authorization header

Comment: You can do like this.  token = req.headers.authorization.split('Bearer ')[1];

Comment: The token is now null

Comment: Could you please check header is pass or not in http request?